How to sort filtered results in my php table?
In my code I have sorting and filtering options. Sorting allows you to sort data ASC or DESC. With filter you can filter by location, status, urgency, id etc. My current problem is that when I filter by location and I want to sort those filtered results it sorts whole table instead of filtered results. I've tried to resolve this issue with some other codes I've foound on the internet but nothing helped me solve this issue.
I have two files (tickets.php and table.php). In tickets.php I generate the table and in the table.php I use SQL query to display data based on user login state and I also include the previous file (tickets.php)
Here is my code:
tickets.php:
<?php


// Default sorting parameters
$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'id_ticket';
$sort = isset($_GET['sort']) && ($_GET['sort'] === 'DESC' || $_GET['sort'] === 'ASC') ? $_GET['sort'] : 'ASC';

// Toggle sorting direction
$newSort = ($sort === 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

$result = $conn->query($sql);

function getSortUrl($column)
{
    global $order, $sort;
    $newSort = ($order === $column && $sort === 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
    return "table.php?order=$column&sort=$newSort";
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $sort == 'ASC' ? $sort = 'DESC' : $sort = 'ASC';
    echo "<table id='myTable'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th><a class='sort-by' href='table.php?order=id_ticket&sort=$newSort'>Ticket ID</a></th>";
    echo "<th><a class='sort-by' href='table.php?order=nombre&sort=$newSort'>Name</a></th>";
    echo "<th><a class='sort-by' href='table.php?order=localizacion&sort=$newSort'>Location</a></th>";
    echo "<th><a class='sort-by' href='table.php?order=nombre_departamento&sort=$newSort'>Department</a></th>";
    echo "<th><a class='sort-by' href='table.php?order=titulo&sort=$newSort'>Title</a></th>";
    echo "<th><a class='sort-by' href='table.php?order=fecha_creacion&sort=$newSort'>Creation Date</a></th>";
    echo "<th><a class='sort-by' href='table.php?order=estado&sort=$newSort'>Status</a></th>";
    echo "<th><a class='sort-by' href='table.php?order=prioridad&sort=$newSort'>Priority</a></th>";
    echo "<th><a class='sort-by' href='table.php?order=fecha_actualizacion&sort=$newSort'>Last Updated</a></th>";
    echo "<th>Files</th>";
    echo "<th></th> ";
    echo "</tr>";

    // Add dropdowns for filtering above each column header
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' class='filter-input' data-column='0'></td>"; //ID Column
    echo "<td><input type='text' class='filter-input' data-column='1'></td>"; //User column

    // Location filter column
    echo "<td><select class='filter-select' data-column='2'>
                <option value=''>All</option>
                <option value='New York'>New York</option>
                <option value='Los Angeles'>Los Angeles</option>
                <option value='London'>London</option>
                <option value='Paris'>Paris</option>
                <option value='Sydney'>Sydney</option>
                </select></td>";

    // Department filter column
    echo "<td><select class='filter-select' data-column='3'>";
    echo "<option value=''>All</option>";

    $departmentQuery = "SELECT department_name FROM departmenrs WHERE department != 0";
    $departmentResult = $conn->query($departmentQuery);

    if ($departmentResult->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($departmentRow = $departmentResult->fetch_assoc()) {
            $departmentName = $departmentRow['department_name'];
            echo "<option value='$departmentName'>$departmentName</option>";
        }
    }

    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' class='filter-input' data-column='4'></td>"; // Title column

    // Date filter column
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<div class="date-inputs-container">';
    echo '<i class="fas fa-calendar-alt date-filter-icon" onclick="toggleDateInputs(this)"></i>';
    echo '<div class="date-inputs">';
    echo '<label for="start-date">From:</label>';
    echo '<input type="date" id="start-date" class="filter-input" data-column="5"><br>';
    echo '<label for="end-date">To:</label>';
    echo '<input type="date" id="end-date" class="filter-input" data-column="5">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</td>';

    //Status column
    echo "<td><select class='filter-select' data-column='6'>
                  <option value=''>All</option>
                  <option value='Open'>Open</option>
                  <option value='In Progress'>In Progress</option>
                  <option value='On Hold'>On Hold</option>
              </select></td>";

    //Priority column
    echo "<td><select class='filter-select' data-column='7'> 
                  <option value=''>All</option>
                  <option value='New'>New</option>
                  <option value='Urgent'>Urgent</option>
                  <option value='High'>High</option>
                  <option value='Medium'>Medium</option>
                  <option value='Low'>Low</option>
              </select></td>";

    //Last Updated column
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<div class="date-inputs-container">';
    echo '<i class="fas fa-calendar-alt date-filter-icon" onclick="toggleDateInputsLastUpdated(this)"></i>';
    echo '<div class="date-inputs">';
    echo '<label for="last-updated-start-date">From:</label>';
    echo '<input type="date" id="last-updated-start-date" class="filter-input" data-column="8"><br>';
    echo '<label for="last-updated-end-date">To:</label>';
    echo '<input type="date" id="last-updated-end-date" class="filter-input" data-column="8">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</td>';

    echo "<td></td>";
    echo '<td><button id="clearFiltersBtn">Clear Filters</button></td>';
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='incident-id'>" . $row["id_ticket"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["location"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["department_name"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["title"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["created"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='Status'>" . $row["status"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["priority"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='Last_Updated'>" . $row["last_updated"] . "</td>";

        
        echo '</form>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<tr><td colspan='11'>No tickets found.</td></tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
$conn->close();
?>

<script>
    function toggleDateInputs(icon) {
        const dateInputsContainer = icon.nextElementSibling;
        if (dateInputsContainer) {
            dateInputsContainer.classList.toggle('show');
        }
    }

    function toggleDateInputsLastUpdated(icon) {
        const dateInputsContainer = icon.nextElementSibling;
        if (dateInputsContainer) {
            dateInputsContainer.classList.toggle('show');
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const statusSelects = document.querySelectorAll('.status-select');
        statusSelects.forEach(select => {
            select.addEventListener('change', function () {
                console.log('status-select change event fired');
                const row = this.closest('tr');
                const incidentIdElement = row.querySelector('.incident-id');
                const statusCell = row.querySelector('.Status');
                const lastUpdatedCell = row.querySelector('.Last_Updated');

                // Send AJAX request to update status
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                const incidentId = incidentIdElement.textContent.trim(); // Retrieve incident ID
                const status = this.value; // Retrieve selected status
                const params = `incident_id=${incidentId}&status=${encodeURIComponent(status)}`;
                lastUpdatedCell
                xhr.open('POST', 'includes/update_status.php', true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        // Update status and time in cell using response
                        const updatedTimestamp = xhr.responseText;
                        console.log('Updated Timestamp:', updatedTimestamp);

                        if (lastUpdatedCell) {
                            lastUpdatedCell.textContent = updatedTimestamp;
                        } else {
                            console.error('Last Updated Cell not found.');
                        }

                        if (statusCell) {
                            statusCell.textContent = status;
                        } else {
                            console.error('Status Cell not found.');
                        }

                        alert('Status updated successfully');
                    } else {
                        alert('Error updating status: ' + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                };
                xhr.send(params);
            });
        });


        const lastUpdatedStartInput = document.getElementById('last-updated-start-date');
        const lastUpdatedEndInput = document.getElementById('last-updated-end-date');

        if (lastUpdatedStartInput && lastUpdatedEndInput) {
            lastUpdatedStartInput.addEventListener('change', applyLastUpdatedFilter);
            lastUpdatedEndInput.addEventListener('change', applyLastUpdatedFilter);
        }

        function applyLastUpdatedFilter() {
            const table = document.getElementById('myTable');
            const tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            const rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');

            const startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('last-updated-start-date').value);
            const endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('last-updated-end-date').value);

            endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1); // Include the selected end date

            for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                const row = rows[i];
                const lastUpdatedCell = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(9)'); 

                if (lastUpdatedCell) {
                    const lastUpdatedDate = new Date(lastUpdatedCell.textContent.trim());

                    const isVisible =
                        (!startDate || lastUpdatedDate >= startDate) &&
                        (!endDate || lastUpdatedDate <= endDate);

                    row.style.display = isVisible ? '' : 'none';
                }
            }
        }

        const filterInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-input');
        const filterSelects = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-select');

        filterInputs.forEach(input => {
            input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
                const columnIndex = this.dataset.column;
                filterTable(columnIndex, this.value.trim());
            });
        });

        filterSelects.forEach(select => {
            select.addEventListener('change', function () {
                const columnIndex = this.dataset.column;
                filterTable(columnIndex, this.value);
            });
        });

        // Function filters data based on the input field values
        function filterTable() {
            const table = document.getElementById('myTable');
            const tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]; 
            const rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');

            for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                const row = rows[i];
                const cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
                let shouldDisplay = true;

                for (let j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                    const targetCell = cells[j];
                    const filterInput = document.querySelector(`.filter-input[data-column="${j}"]`);
                    const filterSelect = document.querySelector(`.filter-select[data-column="${j}"]`);

                    if (filterInput) {
                        const inputValue = filterInput.value.trim().toUpperCase();
                        if (inputValue !== '' && inputValue !== 'Todo') {
                            const cellText = targetCell.textContent || targetCell.innerText;
                            if (cellText.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue) === -1) {
                                shouldDisplay = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (filterSelect) {
                        const selectValue = filterSelect.value.trim().toUpperCase();
                        if (selectValue !== '' && selectValue !== 'Todo') {
                            const cellText = targetCell.textContent || targetCell.innerText;
                            if (j === 7 && cellText.toUpperCase() !== selectValue) { 
                                shouldDisplay = false;
                                break;
                            } else if (j !== 7 && cellText.toUpperCase().indexOf(selectValue) === -1) {
                                shouldDisplay = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                row.style.display = shouldDisplay ? '' : 'none';
            }
        }

        const clearFiltersBtn = document.getElementById('clearFiltersBtn');
        if (clearFiltersBtn) {
            clearFiltersBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

                // Clear all input values
                filterInputs.forEach(input => {
                    input.value = '';
                });

                // Reset all select elements to their first option (All)
                filterSelects.forEach(select => {
                    select.selectedIndex = 0;
                });

                // Trigger filterTable function to reset table display
                filterTable('', '');
            });
        };
    });


</script>

table.php:

    <body>
        <?php
        $pageTitle = "Tickets";
        include 'connection.php';


        if (isset($_GET['order'])) {
            $order = $_GET['order'];
        } else {
            $order = 'title';
        }

        if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
            $sort = $_GET['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'ASC';
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
            $departmentID = $_SESSION['department_id'];
            if ($departmentID == 0) {
                $sql = "SELECT tickets.id_ticket, tickets.name, tickets.location, tickets.priority, department.department_name, tickets.title, tickets.created, tickets.status, tickets.last_updated, COUNT(files.id_archivo) AS FileCount
                FROM tickets
                INNER JOIN department ON tickets.id_departament = departament.id_departament
                LEFT JOIN files ON tickets.id_ticket = file.id_ticket
                WHERE tickets.hidden = 0
                GROUP BY tickets.id_ticket
                ORDER BY tickets.title ASC";

            } 
        }

        include 'tickets.php';

        ?>
    </body>


The sort options need to be input fields in your form (i.e. select the field to sort on, and the direction to sort in, rather than a separate hyperlink, so that the sort and filter options are all submitted together to the server, so that PHP can take account of all them when building and returning the results. Or if you'd prefer to keep the current user experience, you'll need a way for PHP to remember the current filter, or for the current filter options to be passed in the hyperlinks. Basically, you have to bring it all together - how exactly you do it is up to you

Actually I just noticed that you seem to be doing the filtering client-side, and the sorting server-side. So yeah that's fundamentally incompatible, too. You need to do all the operations one side or the other really.

Thanks for this answer, I'll have to look it up

Your SQL doesn't work, right?  I see a table called files, then an attempt to join on id_ticket from the file table.

no SQL works it is a typo I made when I edited code for stackoverflow

Don't really know your needs, but if just display/sort data in html table from sql DB, why not use DataTables? (https://datatables.net)
You can convert HTML table (adding sorting option, etc) (client side) or use server side processing.

Taking the advice of @ADyson I've changed the table headers so it doesn't display the url when you click on it.
    echo "<th class='sort-by'><a href='#' data-column='0'>ID Ticket <i class='fas fa-sort'></i></a></th>";
    echo "<th><a href='#' data-column='1'>Name <i class='fas fa-sort'></i></a></th>";
    echo "<th><a href='#' data-column='2'>Location <i class='fas fa-sort'></i></a></th>";
    echo "<th><a href='#' data-column='3'>Department <i class='fas fa-sort'></i></a></th>";
    echo "<th><a href='#' data-column='4'>Title <i class='fas fa-sort'></i></a></th>";
    echo "<th><a href='#' data-column='5'>Creation Time <i class='fas fa-sort'></i></a></th>";
    echo "<th><a href='#' data-column='6'>Status <i class='fas fa-sort'></i></a></th>";
    echo "<th><a href='#' data-column='7'>Priority <i class='fas fa-sort'></i></a></th>";
    echo "<th><a href='#' data-column='8'>Last Updated <i class='fas fa-sort'></i></a></th>";
    echo "<th>Files</th>";

In the script inside the document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () I've added this function that allows me to sort the data in my table including the one I've filtered. This achieves what I originally intended to do.
function sortTable(columnIndex, order) {
            const table = document.getElementById('myTable');
            const tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            const rows = Array.from(tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr'));

            rows.sort((a, b) => {
                const aValue = a.getElementsByTagName('td')[columnIndex].textContent.trim();
                const bValue = b.getElementsByTagName('td')[columnIndex].textContent.trim();

                return isNaN(aValue) ? aValue.localeCompare(bValue) : aValue - bValue;
            });

            if (order === 'DESC') {
                rows.reverse();
            }

            rows.forEach(row => tbody.appendChild(row));
        }

        const headers = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable th');
        headers.forEach((header, index) => {
            header.addEventListener('click', function () {
                const columnIndex = index; // Index of the clicked column
                const order = this.dataset.sort === 'DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'; 
                sortTable(columnIndex, order);
                this.dataset.sort = order; 
            });
        });

